# AutoFixture - how do I call a method, how to set a private setter of an autoproperty?

Tags: c#, autofixture

Here's my class:

```
public MyClass {
  public int Id { get; private set; }
  public SetAssignableId (int id) {
    this.Id = id;
  }
}
```

I would like to have AutoFixture set the Id via SetAssignableId or the private setter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to invoke a private setter with AutoFixture today. Although it uses reflection internally, by design it respects a type's public API.

There's an [outstanding request on the Issue Board](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/workitem/4200) to make this more customizable - if you read the work item closely you will see that there's a request to enable filling of protected setters.

However, with the example given, it's certainly possible to invoke the SetAssignableId method. A Customization like this should do the trick:

```
fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => 
    c.Do(mc => 
        mc.SetAssignableId(fixture.CreateAnonymous<int>())));
```