# Create a list of objects by an example object

Tags: c#, autofixture, test-data

I want AutoFixture to create a list of an object by using an example object.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

var examplePerson = new Person { Name = "Test", Age = 34 };
var persons = fixture.CreateMany<Person>();
```

Conventions I would like to have:

- create string with max. length of the provided string length (4 in this example)
- create integers where the max.  amount of the computed digits equals the provided digits
- with a decimal of 14.99 create similar decimals like 93.12
- and so on

So I want AutoFixture to learn from my given example object.

Is this possible :)?

Comment: What you describe might be possible but it will probably result to a unit test which is difficult to write. Please, consider the [3rd paragraph from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22708291/467754) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible :)?

No, AutoFixture has no built-in AI.